# Mobile Website Security

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a mobile website and I want users with authorized devices to visit the website. The authorized device id is stored in the server database.

My question is that is there a way to retrieve the device id when browsing a mobile website. I do not think that it is possible and I might have to adjust to a username, password solution.

Comment: Not for webpages but if you use something like PhoneGap you can get the device ID as you are in a native environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right: it's not possible. You will need to come up with a user/pass solution.

**IF** your are able to get a carrier agreement (it might vary from difficult to impossible depending on what country you're in), you can ask the carrier to add an extended **HTTP** header with the phone number to the navigating device. That way you can identify the device browsing with its phone number.